What’s the correct bubble gasket replacement
The gasket on the bottom of my upvc front door (I think it’s a storm guard) has disintegrated and I’m trying to find a replacement.
This is the current gasket

Measurements are roughly

Top:4.3mm
Middle: 2.3mm
Bubble: 10mm

And I can see 3 small bits on the top inner tube (don’t know if it’s relevant)
I’ve tried the following from a sample pack but none matched or fit the door

Anyone know what the gasket is?

IDK if this would do you for: https://www.swisco.com/3-16-3-8/pd/Bubble-Seal/58-135
